# How to uninstall Nomachine

Tags: uninstall

I want to remove 'NOMACHINE' from my computer, but I can't see it in software manage. I tried to delete the files but, some are locked.

How should I proceed?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: From 'Nomachine' site; i download it and click to the downloaded file :)

Comment: it is not important, i am just curios :)

Comment: the file is/was :'NoMachine for Linux - amd64' debian edition :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As it says in the instructions:

```
sudo dpkg -r nomachine
```

See [here](https://www.nomachine.com/DT09K00056#4.2.).

Comment: I can't vote you, i am not enough reputation. but, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

The uninstall instructions are on NoMachine web (https://www.nomachine.com/DT02O00124#2.4):

> **UNINSTALL**
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/NX/scripts/setup/nxserver --uninstall
> ```
>
> then, remove the installation dir:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /usr/NX
> ```

Comment: works also in archlinux.